# iOS audio input via USB

Tags: ios, audio, microphone

I am working on a project where I need to process 4 channels of audio input, simultaneously, and in real time on an iOS device.  I cannot find any compact 4-input USB audio interfaces claiming to be compatible with iOS. Do external USB audio interfaces connected via the camera connection kit need to be authenticated to work with apple devices?

Will any class compliant USB audio interface work?

Answer (score 2):

[This one](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/iOMix/) (Alesis) might do the job. Still most audio devices are still 2 x 4. [This one](http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2013/02/06/apogee-quartet-now-ipad-compatible/) (Apogee) is also new but expensive. There is a great site for [iOS Music](http://iosmusician.com) (IOSmusicians.com) and they are talking about [this device](http://www.iconnectivity.com/iConnectMIDI4plus) (IOSConnectMIDI4Plus)